# Window frozen on drawing shape

Tags: .net, wpf, multithreading, drawing

I have a [Canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx) inside my WPF Window, and I want to draw a huge number of shapes (about hundred thousand shapes or more). Something like this:

```
<Window>
<Canvas>
    <!--<Shape1/>
    <Shape2/>
    ... and so on ... -->
</Canvas>
</Window>
```

To draw shapes i have a method that does a job like this:

```
public void DrawShape()
{
    // Create the shape
    ShapeT MyShape = new ShapeT();
    // Set shape's properties (like Width, Fill, ...)

    // Add shape as MyCanvas children.
    MyCanvas.Children.Add(MyShape);
}
```

Then to draw, for example, forty thousand shapes I do:

```
for (uint i = 0; i < 0x9C40; ++i)
     DrawShape();
```

**The problems are:**

1. Until all the figures are not drawn, i.e until the loop is completed, no figure is drawn and my window not responding for all time.
2. Even after the loop has been completed, it still takes several seconds before the figures are drawn on the video, and my window continues to be frozen.

I tried to use [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.aspx):

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new MyDrawDelegate(DrawShape));
```

I tried to create a new thread:

```
Thread DrawThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DrawShape));
DrawThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
DrawThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
DrawThread.Start();
```

but there were no changes.
How can I fix these problems?

PS: for performance reasons I draw my shapes using [Visual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.aspx) and not [Shape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.aspx) objects.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know WPF (until 3.5) has only one thread allowed to access WPF objects so I think you need to optimize it not with threading.

So for example: do you need all your shapes are showed togheter? Can you load only a subset of them and load some others object in a second time?

Comment: The thread you speak of is the UI Thread, but you can use Dispatcher to access to your elements in another thread. How can I prevent the window does not respond without using a thread that is not the UI thread? I need to load all shapes at the same time. Also, considering that draw hundreds of thousands of shapes requires considerable time, and I would not having to put even more time by stopping the process and then resume it.

Comment: Dispatcher is just a way to synchronize other threads with UI thread through a message pump. Unfortunately the delegate specified in BeginInvoke call is executed by UI thread.

Comment: And how can I do to run the delegate from a thread that is not the UI thread?

Comment: I guess is not possible to use UI object in a non UI thread.
Something new is coming with wpf 4.5 however I suppose it will be a transparent way to synchronyze with the UI thread.

I think you should find some other way to optimize your code.
Can you explain a bit more about what you are trying to do and why you need a huge nuber of different visual objects?

Comment: Of course, I have to parse an [SVG](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/) file (XML format) and draw the relative vector image. For each new element in the SVG file, i create a new shape and i add it to my panel. During this work my Window has the behavior that I explained in my question.

Comment: Do you want to view all the SVG file in your Canvas or you have scrollbars and you view just a part of it per time? In the second case you can use Virtual Canvas (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2008/03/08/performant-virtualized-wpf-canvas.aspx). I already tryed it and works pretty good.

Comment: I have scrollbars, but i think that Virtual Canvas is not a better solution for two reasons: 1) Virtual Canvas bases his performance on the fact that a shape is only created at the time is displayed in the video, thus if there are a lot of shapes the performance is worse than the "traditional" Canvas, while if there are few shapes (when i zoom for example) I have no problems to quickly view these shapes because in this case Canvas does its job well.

Comment: 2) As i said, i create my shape parsing SVG file, thus i only know at that time as to create the shape, instead with Virtual Canvas I have to store all the information about all shapes if I want to recreate the figures to be displayed in the selected area.

Comment: "1" is a good point, but I have few doubts on "2": you can load your informations in model object that can be read by the VirtualCanvas when is necessary. BTW "1" is enought

Comment: So.. 2 things comes in my mind:
- try to group more SVG object in a single shape
- use bitmap instead of vectorial objects. I'm not sure but maybe in this case you can prepare the bitmap in a background thread

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use vector graphics, my images have to be scaled by any amount without degrading quality.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Dispatcher,it might be the case where your ArangePass is taking long time to render the updated changes to  UI.
You can make your parent container to wait by adding following code snippet:

```
  using (var temporaryPresentationSource = new HwndSource(new HwndSourceParameters()) { RootVisual = (VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(yourRenderTarget) == null ? yourRenderTarget: null) })
        {
            // Flush the dispatcher queue
            yourRenderTarget.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, 
            new Action(() => {/*required action*/ }));
         }
```

Give it a try, it worked for me..!!

Comment: Could you explain it better with a more complete example? For example, where should I use your code?

Comment: Sorry for creating ambiguity, if you want to flush your DrawShape Code on the Dispatcher then you can specify your code in /*required action*/ space, now as you said, when you use dispatcher the changes are not reflecting, it means that the changes are not rendered. To force rendering you can use the Source Window Handle which will wait for canvas to finish its rendering.

Comment: I tried your solution in [this](http://ideone.com/BkCvl) way, but it does not work. I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: The way you tried looks good, but what problem it is giving to you now? Can you elaborate..?

Comment: No problems have been solved (until the loop is completed, no figure is drawn and my window not responding for all time).